# Having problems creating MX records for subdomain on dreamhost.

Tags: dns

I have a domain on dreamhost, say block.com. This domain points to an address outside of dreamhost (amazon AWS).

I also have a subdomain, us.block.com that is hosted on AWS. This subdomain is not registered on dreamhost (as dreamhost doesn't allow subdomains to be hosted outside of dreamhost). To point to this subdomain, I've added in a couple of custom A records to the DNS records on dreamhost.

Since the subdomain is not registered on dreamhost, it doesn't allow me to add custom MX records. Is there anyway to get around this? If there isn't, can I somehow point the mail server of us.block.com to that of block.com without using mx records?

Comment: `dreamhost doesn't allow subdomains to be hosted outside of dreamhost` I am not at all familiar with their service, but I find this hard to believe, in the 21st century

Comment: I realise how ludicrous it sounds, but it's true. While you can input any custom dns records you want (and thus theoretically redirect to any subdomain, inside or outside of IS), if you want to get access to a subdomain's mx records, you need to 'register' it with dreamhost, which implicitly implies hosting it with dreamhost. Once you've registered, dreamhost doesn't allow you to change the subdomain to being one that is hosted outside of dreamhost. Which is making things really difficult for me right now.

Comment: I have just checked their site knowledge base, indeed they have strange way of setting MX records.

Comment: Is it possible to add NS records for _subdmain_, I can't see from their screenshots?

Comment: Yeah, it does. Can I use that to point the subdomain to the same mailserver as the domain?

Comment: you can use it to point subdomain to other name server (AWS for example), then create subdomain zone on AWS Route53, and configure MX records there

Comment: (you will first have to create subdomain zone on AWS, in order to get exact nameservers for your subdomain)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a little trick:

1. Domains > Manage Domains
2. Fully host your subdomain
3. Under "Web Hosting" find "Remove" and press it
4. Now you can edit custom MX fields for your subdomain

Tested solution from [here](https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-131664-post-144033.html#pid144033)